# Как можно понять Latutude,Longitude,Azimuth пришедший из сервера?

Tags: геолокация, карты

Привет всем.
У меня есть месторасположение магазинов. Я взял эти данные с местного сервера.
Но, я не понимаю как можно перевести в нормальный вид для отображение на карте.

Longitude: **156333556**
Latitude: **27975214**
Azimuth: **256**

Comment: Вы знаете где этот магазин находится?

Comment: Да, знаю. Оно находится в городел Алматы.

Comment: Здесь использовался оператор сдвига лево и вправо для сокрытие координаты. Все окей, проблема решена.

Comment: Вот пример! Надеюсь разберёшься! [прим1.](https://yadi.sk/d/T9knf2KR0OwH_Q)
[прим2.](https://yadi.sk/d/RhbFeuubQ3c22Q) Если что, то можешь спрашивать, но код для 8 класса!

Answer (score 0):

Путем, поиск и проб, я вычислил координаты. Здесь использовался оператор сдвига влево и вправо для сокрытие координаты от третьих лиц. Все окей, проблема решена.